# Where do I connect the negative and positive wires on this motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor

Pulled a motor from a broken frother and accidently broke the connections and would like to turn it into a hand crank generator for fun 
Thanks here's a photo 
[image: cool spinny electricity makes me happy]

Apparently this is a rotor not a motor. I'll be looking up the difference now

Comment: This is not a motor. It's a *rotor*.

Comment: Why not just get a new motor and save yourself time reassembling the stator/magnets and commutator.

Comment: My mistake didn't know it was a rotor. I'd happily buy another in interested in how it was connected for educational purposes

Comment: That's just the innards of the motor - the bit that moves. You're missing the outer bits which will be a set of permanent magnets mounted in a housing, and a set of *brushes* which supply power to the coils in the bit you're holding.

Answer (score 5):

The photo shows the rotor of a very small DC motor. The stator in the housing almost certainly has permanent magnets. At one end of the housing, there should be two thin pieces of brass that slide on the commutator that you see on the shaft at the end of the motor facing you in the picture. Those two pieces should be connected to wires or terminals. It makes no difference which is positive. If you turn the rotor one way, one will be positive. Of you turn it the other way, the other will be positive.

The following picture shows all of the parts of a very similar motor:

[image]

Here is a picture that shows the details of the commutator and brushes as they would be when the motor is fully assembled. Each of the two brushes is i single piece of brass with two prongs contacting the commutator.

[image]

Comment: I think I may have broke those pieces odd but thank you so much this helped me understand much better. I will update the OP with a photo of the casing. Ok found what you are talking about thank you so much for explaining

Comment: Interesting so the metal prongs just rest on each side of the communicator?

Comment: Yes, but they are springy, so there is a little pressure.

Comment: @SebastianFrederick *Commutator*, not Communicator.

Comment: If you have broken or lost the end piece with the brushes, you probably can not do anything to replace it. The bearing in the center must be quite precisely in the center to hold the shaft properly.  There is slightly more room for error in replacing the brush pieces.